# Consistency of two C FILE* streams on a single file

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux, crt

I need to implement a simple "spill to disk" layer for large volume of data coming off a network socket.  I was hoping to have two C `FILE*` streams, one used by a background thread writing to the file, one used by a front end thread reading it.

The two streams are so one thread can be writing at one offset, while the other is reading elsewhere - without taking a lock and blocking the other thread.

There will be a paging mechanism so the reads/writes are at random access locations - not necessarily sequential.

One more caveat, this needs to work on Windows and Linux.

The question: after the fwrite to the first stream has returned, is that written data guaranteed to be immediately visible to an fread on the second stream?

If not, what other options might I consider?

---

So Posix pread/pwrite functions turned out to be what I needed.  Here's a version for Win32:

```
size_t pread64(int fd, void* buf, size_t nbytes, __int64 offset)
{
    OVERLAPPED ovl;
    memset(&ovl, 0, sizeof(ovl));
    *((__int64*)&ovl.Offset)=offset;

    DWORD nBytesRead;
    if (!ReadFile((HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd), buf, nbytes, &nBytesRead, &ovl))
        return -1;

    return nBytesRead;
}

size_t pwrite64(int fd, void* buf, size_t nbytes, __int64 offset)
{
    OVERLAPPED ovl;
    memset(&ovl, 0, sizeof(ovl));
    *((__int64*)&ovl.Offset)=offset;

    DWORD nBytesWritten;
    if (!WriteFile((HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd), buf, nbytes, &nBytesWritten, &ovl))
        return -1;

    return nBytesWritten;
}
```

(And thank you everyone for input on this - much appreciated).

Comment: How much data per second is this, how long does it take to process it, and how fast are your drives?  Having two threads seeking to different parts of a file on a disc every timeslice is probably going to make the hard drive act like Mix-Master Mike.  Have you considered a memory-mapped file?

Comment: @gpcz: Only on a really broken OS would writes actually result in seeks on the underlying storage medium...

Comment: @gpcz: there will be a layer of paged caching on top of this (I simplified the problem for the question) so I'm not concerned about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely will not give you the semantics you want. If you disabled buffering, it might be reasonable to expect it to work, but I still don't think there are any guarantees. Stdio/`FILE` is really not the right tool for specialized IO needs like this.

The POSIX way to do what you want is with file descriptors and the `pread`/`pwrite` functions. I suspect there's a Windows way (or you could emulate them based on some other underlying Windows primitive) but I don't know it.

Also Ben's suggestion of using memory-mapped IO is a very good one, assuming the file fits in your address space.

Comment: pread/pwrite are exactly what I'm looking for.  Just need a solution for Windows now.  Closest I've found is overlapped IO which allows specifying an offset, but I want synchronous IO with offset.

Comment: @Brad: On Windows, just use `DuplicateHandle`.  Each handle has its own file pointer.

Comment: @Ben: Are you sure? Just wrote a quick test app, looks like they share the same file pointer.

Comment: @Brad: Ack, you're right.  MSDN even says so, sorry I missed that.  You can always start an OVERLAPPED operation and then wait for it immediately.

Comment: @Brad: Oh wait a minute.  This is EASY.  Open the file without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, then pass an OVERLAPPED structure anyway.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747.aspx#synchronization_and_file_position and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467.aspx#synchronization_and_file_position

Comment: @Ben - thanks Ben.  Yeah I just figured that out too.  Just need to abstract the platform specifics away and I think I'm all set.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a great fit for memory-mapped I/O.  It's guaranteed to be coherent, very fast, and keeping track of multiple pointers is straightforward.

You'll need different functions to set up the memory mapping on different OSes, but the actual I/O is completely portable (using pointer deference).

- linux: `open`, `mmap`
- Windows: `CreateFileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile`

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I had considered memory mapped files, but as suggested by "R.." there's the possibility that it's not going to fit in the address space.  (actually I find that really hard to believe, but that's what I'm being told).

Comment: @Brad: Memory-mapping creates a "window" or "view" into the file, which represents only part of the file.  The address space requirement is dependent on the extent of the view.  It's easiest to view the whole file, but if your files are large you'll need some extra OS-specific code to manage a smaller view.

Comment: Right... I was considering MMFs but I'd need to manage partial views on the file - at which point I realised I might as well just do the read/writes myself as it fits better with the paging I'm doing anyway.